# How to get the url with application name in .net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url, iis

Is there any way that I get the host address with the Application Name in IIS of my websites? To make my question clear here are few examples of what I want:

```
http://example.com/constructionSite/myController/myAction?blah=blahh
http://example.com/tr.Implementation/myOtherController/myAction?blah=blahh
http://example.com/anotherApplication/myController/myAction?blah=blahh
http://example.com/myOtherOtherController/myAction?blah=blahh
```

In my IIS I have applications like those above `constructionSite, tr.Implementation, anotherApplication, myController`. I need to get the urls with the application names on IIS, in other words up until the `myController/.....`. And `myController` will not allways be the same controller, so I cannot use `.IndexOf()` method.

I tried playing with `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath` these paths, but it doesn't satisfy me.

What should be the appropriate approach to get the url with application name?

Comment: Are they in the same asp.net application or not? If so, use the routes and route values. Required reading: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/controllers-and-routing.

Comment: They are different applications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try using Url.Content("~")

```
@string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Authority, Url.Content("~"))
```

Comment: I think the question is: how to get the application name, not how to format an url.

Comment: i think the point is to get the url with the base virtual path. anyway, the main part is Url.Content("~"), that returns the virtual path of the application.